# Ruby: how to check if an UTF-8 string contains only letters and numbers?

Tags: ruby, unicode, utf-8, character-properties

I have an UTF-8 string, which might be in any language.

How do I check, if it does not contain any non-alphanumeric characters?

I could not find such method in UnicodeUtils Ruby gem.

Examples:

1. ėččę91 - valid
2. $120D - invalid

Comment: Which version of Ruby? 1.8 has limited multi-byte capability. 1.9+ has it in spades.

Comment: I am using the latest one - 1.92

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the POSIX notation for alpha-numerics:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -w
# encoding: UTF-8

puts RUBY_VERSION

valid = "ėččę91"
invalid = "$120D"

puts valid[/[[:alnum:]]+/]
puts invalid[/[^[:alnum:]]+/]
```

Which outputs:

```
1.9.2
ėččę91
$
```

Comment: Is that the same as `[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Number}]`?

Answer (score 1):

In ruby regex \p{L} means any letter (in any glyph)

so if s represents your string:

```
 s.match /^[\p{L}\p{N}]+$/
```

This will filter out non numbers and letters.

Comment: You have `\d` but `\d` is **not numbers!** `\pN` is numbers, or rubyspeak, the `\p{N}` verbosity.  `\d` is only `\p{Decimal_Number}` a.k.a. `\p{Numeric_Type=Decimal}` Not that Ruby bothers to support all the Unicode properties  like that, but anyway 1.9 is better than 1.8.  Still a long ways to go, though.

Comment: Thanks for that, I updated answer to be more precise with numbers.

Comment: **Technically speaking,** there are just over 1,000 code points which are of type `\p{Alphabetic}` but which are not `\p{Letter}`. This especially matters if you haven’t normalized to NFC form, or have decompoposed to NFD or NFKD, but in fact can actually occur in even NFC forms, too.  Just depends.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern for one alphanumeric code point is

```
/[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Number}]/
```

From there it’s easy to extrapolate something like this for has a negative:

```
/[^\p{Alphabetic}\p{Number}]/
```

or this for is all positive:

```
 /^[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Number}]+$/
```

or sometimes this, depending:

```
/\A[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Number}]+\z/
```

Pick the one that best suits your needs.